# I can't sync photos from my iPhone 3gs to my mac

Tags: mac, data-synchronization, photos, iphone

I can't to sync the photos from the camera roll on my iPhone 3gs to my mac. I have had slight water damage to the phone in the past yet it is still functioning. When I went to see someone about this problem they said it was because of the water damage that it did not work and they would have to fix it but may risk losing data on the phone hence defeating the purpose and being completely counterproductive. When I connect the phone to any windows or mac, it is not recognised by the computer but the charging icon appears on the phone. I have tried all of the options that can be googled but none of them help or are clear enough to make any sense. Could someone write a step-by-step explanation of some options that could fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud backup works if you have iOS6.  You must be connected to wifi and plugged into the charger for this to work. 
http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/17/getting-ready-for-ios-7-how-to-backup-your-device-setup-ios-7/

iOS 5 should be able to backup / sync via WiFi  Google "How to Set Up Wi-Fi Sync in iOS 5"

If iCloud doesn't work for you... you should be able to save your photos using dropbox:  http://www.idownloadblog.com/2013/08/15/back-up-iphone-photos/